# Why does AWS keep saying my ARN is invalid?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to deploy an API Gateway with Lambda integration and I can't get around one particular error. I've checked some posts that took about making sure you've followed the request format, which I believe I have. The error I keep receiving is:

> Invalid ARN specified in the request: Integrations of type 'AWS_PROXY'
> currently only supports Lambda function and Firehose stream
> invocations (Service: AmazonApiGatewayV2; Status Code: 400; Error
> Code: BadRequestException;

This is what my CloudFormation looks like:

```
Parameters:
EnvType:
    Type: String
    Default: "dev"

Resources:
    routerLambda:
            Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
            Properties:
                 FunctionName: !Sub router-${EnvType}
                 ...

    routerLambdaIntegration:
            Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Integration
            Properties:
                ApiId: !Ref apiGateway
                IntegrationType: AWS_PROXY
                IntegrationUri: !Sub "arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:function:router-dev/invocation"
            DependsOn: routerLambda
```

Can anyone see what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a small typo in the URI, you have `invocation` instead of `invocations`

it should be

```yaml
    Target: arn:aws:apigateway:{region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:{region}:{account-id}:function:{function-name}/invocations
```

but you have

```yaml
  IntegrationUri: !Sub "arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:function:router-dev/invocation"
```

Comment: Man, I've triple checked this and failed to spot it :( Thanks for the extra pair of eyes.

Comment: @Ian it happens, been there myself many times. What I try to do is most of the time take the basic examples from the [documentations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigatewayv2-api.html#aws-resource-apigatewayv2-api--examples) and then build on top of it.